# How to receive notification if mod_md fails to renew a certificate?

Tags: apache-2.4, lets-encrypt

One of my site's certificates failed to renew using the mod_md apache module. I was wondering how can I set up my server to send an email notification if this happens in the future?

I looked at logwatch but seems that its httpd script doesn't handle such situation.

Using Amazon Linux, Apache 2.4

Comment: `cron`+`openssl` and check the certificate expire date

Comment: I was thinking more along a cron to parse the apache logs and check for mod_md errors but couldn't find anything already implemented for that purpose.